# NetworkX - Stop Nodes from Bunching Up - Tried Scale/K parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have ~28 nodes with edges between most of them, and some being isolated (no edges).  The isolated nodes are spread out nicely, but the ones which are connected are so stacked I cannot see anything.  I've tried a variety of node_sizes, scale and k parameters and it always gives me (roughly) the same result.  Any way to force a nicer view?

```
nx.draw_spring(candidateGraph, node_size = 1000, with_labels=True, scale=100, weight=weightVal, k=100)

plt.show( )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.

First a comment on how networkx draws things.  Here's the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html).  It creates a dictionary `pos` which has the coordinates of each node.  Using `draw_networkx` you can send the optional argument `pos=my_position_dict` to it.

Networkx also has commands that will define the positons for you.  This way you can have more control over things.

You have several options to do what you want.

The simplest is to plot just the connected component and leave out the isolated nodes.

```
nodes_of_largest_component  = max(nx.connected_components(G), key = len)
largest_component = G.subgraph(nodes_of_largest_component)
nx.draw_spring(largest_component)
```

Another would be to try one of the other (non-spring) layouts.  For example:

```
nx.draw_spectral(G)
```

Alternately, you can start manipulating the positions.  One way is to set a couple positions as fixed and let spring_layout handle the rest.

```
pre_pos = {Huck: (0,0), Christie:(0,1), Graham:(1,1), Bush: (1,2)}
my_pos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos=pre_pos, fixed = pre_pos.keys())
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos=my_pos)
```

Then it will hold the nodes fixed that you've specified in `fixed`.

Alternately, define all the positions for just the largest component.  Then hold those fixed and add the other nodes.  The largest component will "fill" most of the available space, and then I **think** spring_layout will try to keep the added nodes from being too far away (alternately once you see the layout, you can specify these by hand).

```
nodes_of_largest_component  = max(nx.connected_components(G), key = len)
largest_component = G.subgraph(nodes_of_largest_component)
pos = nx.spring_layout(largest_component)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G,pos=pos,fixed=nodes_of_largest_component)
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos=pos)
```

One more thing to be aware of is that each call to `spring_layout` will result in a different layout.  This is because it starts with some random positions.  This is part of why it's useful to save the position dictionary, particularly if you plan to do anything fancy with the figure.