# How can I place networkx nodes with the most connections closer to the top?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a fairly large and messy network of nodes that I wish to display as neatly as possible.

This is how it's currently being displayed:
[image: example]

First, I tried playing with the layout to see if it could generate a good output automatically.

I have tried many different nx layouts, but they all display similar results. I have also tried answers from all of these stack exchange questions:

[How to increase node spacing for networkx.spring_layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283341/how-to-increase-node-spacing-for-networkx-spring-layout)

[Drawing a huge graph with networkX and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402255/drawing-a-huge-graph-with-networkx-and-matplotlib)

[NetworkX - Stop Nodes from Bunching Up - Tried Scale/K parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724909/networkx-stop-nodes-from-bunching-up-tried-scale-k-parameters)

[Fix position of subset of nodes in NetworkX spring graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035039/fix-position-of-subset-of-nodes-in-networkx-spring-graph)

Here is the code I am using:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\

def generate_plot(connections, filename):

    G=nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(connections)

    nx.draw(G)

    plt.show()
    #plt.savefig(filename)
```

and here is the data that I am trying to display:

```py
connections = [(0, 36), (0, 113), (2, 11), (2, 12), (2, 26), (2, 27), (2, 28), (2, 29), (2, 32), (2, 33), (2, 34), (2, 35), (2, 82), (3, 41), (4, 41), (5, 3), (6, 3), (11, 7), (11, 10), (11, 13), (11, 42), (12, 10), (12, 164), (26, 10), (26, 100), (27, 10), (27, 164), (28, 10), (28, 92), (29, 56), (29, 58), (29, 79), (29, 91), (29, 99), (29, 100), (29, 101), (29, 102), (30, 59), (30, 83), (30, 99), (31, 55), (31, 56), (31, 57), (31, 74), (31, 91), (31, 96), (31, 100), (31, 113), (31, 134), (31, 164), (32, 10), (33, 10), (34, 10), (34, 164), (35, 10), (35, 91), (35, 100), (36, 64), (36, 74), (36, 82), (36, 91), (36, 107), (36, 99), (38, 41), (39, 40), (39, 41), (39, 59), (40, 41), (40, 47), (40, 91), (40, 99), (41, 3), (41, 39), (41, 40), (43, 68), (43, 69), (45, 50), (46, 51), (46, 69), (46, 99), (47, 49), (47, 91), (47, 107), (47, 100), (47, 101), (47, 113), (48, 76), (50, 68), (50, 69), (51, 68), (51, 76), (51, 114), (52, 46), (52, 47), (52, 65), (53, 42), (53, 107), (53, 99), (53, 100), (53, 101), (53, 113), (54, 76), (55, 74), (55, 96), (55, 99), (56, 99), (56, 100), (56, 109), (57, 29), (57, 64), (57, 91), (57, 96), (57, 107), (57, 100), (58, 91), (58, 99), (58, 100), (58, 101), (58, 102), (59, 30), (59, 46), (59, 47), (59, 61), (59, 83), (59, 99), (59, 100), (59, 101), (60, 3), (60, 12), (60, 26), (60, 27), (60, 29), (60, 30), (60, 31), (60, 35), (60, 36), (60, 40), (60, 42), (60, 44), (60, 49), (60, 55), (60, 56), (60, 57), (60, 58), (60, 59), (60, 61), (60, 64), (60, 74), (60, 75), (60, 79), (60, 81), (60, 82), (60, 83), (60, 86), (60, 90), (60, 91), (60, 92), (60, 93), (60, 94), (60, 96), (60, 107), (60, 99), (60, 100), (60, 101), (60, 102), (60, 111), (60, 112), (60, 113), (60, 116), (60, 126), (60, 129), (60, 134), (60, 135), (60, 136), (60, 140), (60, 144), (60, 150), (60, 152), (60, 162), (60, 164), (60, 179), (60, 195), (61, 91), (61, 107), (61, 100), (61, 101), (61, 113), (61, 135), (62, 79), (62, 102), (63, 59), (64, 29), (64, 36), (64, 91), (64, 99), (64, 100), (64, 101), (64, 140), (65, 12), (65, 27), (65, 29), (65, 30), (65, 31), (65, 34), (65, 35), (65, 43), (65, 45), (65, 50), (65, 56), (65, 57), (65, 58), (65, 59), (65, 60), (65, 61), (65, 66), (65, 67), (65, 72), (65, 75), (65, 81), (65, 82), (65, 91), (65, 92), (65, 96), (65, 107), (65, 99), (65, 100), (65, 101), (65, 102), (65, 104), (65, 109), (65, 129), (65, 140), (65, 142), (65, 156), (65, 164), (67, 68), (67, 69), (67, 195), (68, 60), (69, 51), (69, 53), (69, 68), (69, 195), (70, 12), (70, 26), (70, 29), (70, 31), (70, 35), (70, 47), (70, 56), (70, 58), (70, 59), (70, 61), (70, 66), (70, 75), (70, 79), (70, 82), (70, 83), (70, 93), (70, 96), (70, 107), (70, 99), (70, 100), (70, 101), (70, 126), (70, 129), (70, 135), (70, 136), (70, 162), (70, 164), (71, 12), (71, 26), (71, 29), (71, 31), (71, 35), (71, 47), (71, 56), (71, 58), (71, 59), (71, 61), (71, 66), (71, 75), (71, 79), (71, 83), (71, 96), (71, 107), (71, 99), (71, 100), (71, 101), (71, 126), (71, 135), (71, 162), (71, 164), (72, 29), (72, 35), (72, 36), (72, 46), (72, 47), (72, 55), (72, 57), (72, 58), (72, 60), (72, 61), (72, 64), (72, 66), (72, 70), (72, 71), (72, 74), (72, 75), (72, 76), (72, 79), (72, 86), (72, 90), (72, 91), (72, 93), (72, 94), (72, 95), (72, 96), (72, 107), (72, 99), (72, 100), (72, 101), (72, 102), (72, 111), (72, 112), (72, 116), (72, 126), (72, 129), (72, 144), (73, 83), (74, 96), (74, 100), (75, 100), (76, 29), (76, 31), (76, 42), (76, 44), (76, 49), (76, 55), (76, 56), (76, 59), (76, 61), (76, 66), (76, 74), (76, 78), (76, 83), (76, 91), (76, 93), (76, 96), (76, 107), (76, 109), (76, 113), (76, 114), (76, 116), (76, 134), (76, 140), (77, 30), (77, 44), (77, 49), (77, 61), (77, 74), (77, 78), (77, 83), (77, 96), (77, 109), (77, 140), (78, 61), (78, 91), (78, 92), (79, 44), (79, 99), (80, 42), (80, 64), (80, 65), (80, 75), (80, 83), (80, 134), (80, 135), (80, 136), (80, 144), (80, 155), (81, 35), (81, 91), (81, 100), (82, 10), (83, 84), (83, 85), (83, 86), (83, 107), (83, 100), (84, 194), (84, 195), (87, 36), (87, 88), (87, 142), (87, 144), (88, 59), (88, 83), (88, 134), (88, 135), (88, 136), (88, 144), (88, 158), (88, 162), (89, 61), (89, 135), (89, 141), (90, 36), (91, 96), (91, 113), (93, 96), (93, 107), (93, 134), (93, 135), (94, 74), (94, 96), (95, 61), (95, 134), (95, 135), (95, 162), (96, 35), (96, 74), (96, 91), (96, 99), (96, 100), (96, 101), (98, 12), (98, 26), (98, 27), (98, 29), (98, 30), (98, 31), (98, 34), (98, 35), (98, 41), (98, 56), (98, 57), (98, 58), (98, 59), (98, 60), (98, 61), (98, 70), (98, 75), (98, 79), (98, 81), (98, 82), (98, 83), (98, 84), (98, 87), (98, 91), (98, 92), (98, 95), (98, 96), (98, 107), (98, 99), (98, 100), (98, 101), (98, 106), (98, 134), (98, 135), (98, 142), (98, 147), (98, 152), (98, 159), (99, 91), (99, 113), (99, 164), (100, 91), (100, 101), (100, 113), (100, 164), (101, 57), (101, 91), (101, 113), (101, 164), (102, 101), (103, 44), (103, 61), (103, 140), (104, 56), (104, 90), (104, 101), (104, 102), (104, 104), (104, 129), (104, 140), (105, 83), (105, 135), (106, 2), (106, 29), (106, 30), (106, 31), (106, 36), (106, 41), (106, 48), (106, 56), (106, 57), (106, 58), (106, 59), (106, 60), (106, 61), (106, 62), (106, 63), (106, 65), (106, 66), (106, 68), (106, 70), (106, 71), (106, 72), (106, 74), (106, 75), (106, 76), (106, 77), (106, 78), (106, 79), (106, 80), (106, 81), (106, 82), (106, 83), (106, 84), (106, 85), (106, 87), (106, 89), (106, 90), (106, 91), (106, 92), (106, 93), (106, 94), (106, 95), (106, 96), (106, 107), (106, 99), (106, 100), (106, 101), (106, 102), (106, 103), (106, 104), (106, 105), (106, 108), (106, 110), (106, 111), (106, 112), (106, 116), (106, 119), (106, 123), (106, 124), (106, 125), (106, 126), (106, 127), (106, 128), (106, 129), (106, 130), (106, 131), (106, 134), (106, 135), (106, 136), (106, 137), (106, 138), (106, 139), (106, 140), (106, 141), (106, 142), (106, 144), (106, 146), (106, 147), (106, 148), (106, 149), (106, 151), (106, 152), (106, 153), (106, 154), (106, 157), (106, 158), (106, 159), (106, 160), (106, 161), (106, 162), (106, 164), (106, 194), (108, 42), (108, 61), (108, 76), (108, 109), (108, 110), (108, 114), (109, 42), (109, 91), (109, 113), (109, 164), (110, 76), (111, 114), (112, 114), (114, 0), (114, 26), (114, 29), (114, 30), (114, 31), (114, 35), (114, 36), (114, 40), (114, 42), (114, 44), (114, 47), (114, 49), (114, 53), (114, 55), (114, 56), (114, 57), (114, 59), (114, 61), (114, 64), (114, 74), (114, 75), (114, 81), (114, 82), (114, 86), (114, 91), (114, 93), (114, 96), (114, 107), (114, 99), (114, 100), (114, 101), (114, 102), (114, 109), (114, 129), (114, 134), (114, 135), (114, 140), (114, 164), (114, 179), (115, 10), (115, 31), (115, 164), (116, 114), (119, 150), (120, 157), (121, 137), (122, 137), (123, 163), (124, 117), (124, 125), (124, 130), (124, 150), (124, 163), (125, 126), (126, 117), (126, 135), (127, 134), (128, 135), (129, 36), (129, 91), (130, 131), (131, 134), (131, 135), (132, 157), (133, 137), (134, 36), (134, 74), (134, 109), (134, 135), (135, 36), (135, 74), (135, 136), (135, 156), (136, 36), (137, 134), (138, 139), (139, 135), (140, 107), (140, 134), (140, 136), (141, 118), (141, 135), (141, 144), (142, 36), (142, 61), (142, 64), (142, 83), (142, 118), (142, 129), (142, 134), (142, 135), (142, 136), (142, 140), (142, 141), (142, 143), (142, 144), (142, 150), (142, 152), (142, 156), (142, 158), (142, 162), (142, 164), (142, 195), (143, 135), (144, 36), (144, 134), (144, 135), (144, 136), (144, 162), (145, 134), (146, 134), (146, 135), (146, 155), (147, 29), (147, 44), (147, 46), (147, 47), (147, 118), (147, 134), (147, 135), (147, 136), (147, 140), (147, 144), (147, 156), (147, 158), (147, 164), (148, 136), (148, 150), (149, 134), (149, 135), (149, 136), (149, 141), (150, 134), (150, 164), (151, 150), (152, 134), (152, 135), (152, 156), (152, 162), (153, 134), (153, 135), (153, 162), (154, 150), (155, 134), (156, 135), (157, 134), (158, 136), (158, 140), (159, 135), (160, 134), (160, 135), (160, 155), (162, 36), (162, 61), (162, 74), (162, 96), (162, 134), (162, 135), (162, 144), (167, 171), (168, 83), (169, 99), (170, 83), (170, 85), (171, 2), (172, 195), (173, 78), (174, 78), (175, 60), (175, 66), (175, 70), (175, 142), (176, 94), (176, 120), (176, 121), (176, 122), (176, 123), (176, 132), (176, 133), (176, 137), (176, 138), (176, 145), (176, 157), (177, 12), (177, 26), (177, 27), (177, 28), (177, 29), (177, 30), (177, 31), (177, 33), (177, 34), (177, 35), (177, 36), (177, 44), (177, 55), (177, 56), (177, 57), (177, 58), (177, 59), (177, 61), (177, 62), (177, 63), (177, 64), (177, 74), (177, 75), (177, 78), (177, 79), (177, 81), (177, 82), (177, 86), (177, 89), (177, 90), (177, 91), (177, 93), (177, 94), (177, 96), (177, 107), (177, 99), (177, 100), (177, 101), (177, 102), (177, 109), (177, 113), (177, 118), (177, 128), (177, 129), (177, 134), (177, 135), (177, 136), (177, 139), (177, 140), (177, 141), (177, 144), (177, 148), (177, 149), (177, 150), (177, 151), (177, 152), (177, 153), (177, 154), (177, 159), (177, 162), (178, 35), (180, 37), (182, 31), (183, 31), (184, 185), (185, 29), (185, 30), (185, 31), (185, 44), (185, 79), (185, 166), (185, 187), (185, 190), (187, 185), (188, 164), (188, 187), (188, 190), (189, 108), (190, 185), (192, 193), (195, 164)]
```

I am hoping to be able to spread out the nodes more and display them in a hierarchical manner, with the nodes that have the most connections closer to top, and the ones with few connections at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit roundabout, but maybe useful:

The idea is to use the degree (i.e., its number of edges) of the node as y-coordinate, and then assign x-coords based on frequency of the given degree:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(connections)

# check how many times a given degree occurs:
degrees = [G.degree[a] for a in G.nodes]

# generate unique x-coordinates. divide by 2 for zero-centering: 
degrees = {degree: [a for a in degrees.count(degree)/2. - np.arange(degrees.count(degree))] for degree in set(degrees)}

# build positioning dicitonary:
positions = {a : (degrees[G.degree[a]].pop(), G.degree[a]) for a in G.nodes}
```

[image]

Fixed distances in Y-direction, and slightly less compressed code:

```
degrees = [G.degree[a] for a in G.nodes]
degrees_unique = sorted(list(set(degrees)))
y_positions = {degrees_unique[i] : i for i in range(len(degrees_unique))}
x_positions = {}

for degree in degrees_unique:
x_positions[degree] = [a for a in degrees.count(degree) / 2. - np.arange(degrees.count(degree))]

positions = {}

for node in G.nodes:
    deg = G.degree[node]
    positions[node] = (x_positions[deg].pop(), y_positions[deg])


nx.draw(G, pos=positions, node_size=10)
```

[image]

alternatively, a mirror variable can be included in the last loop, s.t. nodes are plotted above and below the x-axis, every other iteration, somewhat decluttering everything:

```
mirror = 1
for node in G.nodes:
    deg = G.degree[node]
    positions[node] = (x_positions[deg].pop(), mirror*y_positions[deg])
    mirror *= -1

nx.draw(G, pos=positions, node_size=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. I also discovered something that might make the connections a little simpler, so hopefully that makes it look a little less disgusting.